# MySQL WRITE LOCK Not Preventing Inserts

Tags: mysql, locking

This should be a simple task. Can someone tell me why the below code is still inserting rows?

```
lock table wp_postmeta write;
insert into wp_postmeta values (null, 1,'test','test');
```

I've checked my DB user has full global priveleges

Comment: Did you try inserting to the table from a different session or from the same one that locked the table?

Comment: The lock is for you (the session that locks) to use the table exclusively. As the docs explain *"MySQL enables client sessions to acquire table locks explicitly for the purpose of cooperating with other sessions for access to tables, or **to prevent other sessions from modifying tables** during periods when a session requires exclusive access to them"*

Comment: Within the same session. These two statements are executed together

Comment: So, that's expected. What do you want to do? Lock everyone - even you - from using the table? Something like freezing the table? This is not what lock does.

Comment: Thank you for the quick explanations. It appears MySQL is doing what I need it to do. I know now if I want to test a table lock, I need to do so from a new session.